# How to disable default focus highlight on tabhost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Starting Android 8, they set a default focus highlight color of the view that receives the focus. 
I used `android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="false"`to remove default highlight on  my butttons. 
But I can't seem to make it work on my tabhost.
When swiping, it will show the default highlight color on my 2nd tab.

Do you know how to disable the default highlight color on tabhost?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that they have a view created for the indicator of tabhost. So instead of adding `setDefaultFocusHighlightEnabled(false)` to the tabhost, I have added it to the view that they created for the indicator.